# How can I populate a TableView dynamically?

Tags: qt, qml

If I want to build out a TableView dynamically by loading data via AJAX call rather than by specifying list elements manually (like in the code below), how can that be done? I haven't found any examples anywhere yet.

```
ListModel {
    id: dataModel
    ListElement { title:"Image title";  credit:"some author";  source:"http:/..." }
    ListElement { title:"Another title";  credit:"some author";  source:"http:/..." }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the data and then append it to your model.

[The docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method) on `ListModel` are pretty straight forward and clear on how to add data to a model dynamically.

As to making the web request, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-xmlhttprequest-example.html)'s an example on how to fetch data in QML using [XMLHttpRequest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest).

Comment: excellent! sometimes when you're totally new to a particular language/framework it takes a little time to get used to using the docs and third-party resources effectively. I looked for that and somehow just didn't find it even though it's obvious now.